# Create React with Yarn

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amxb0.png)

I want to create react app with yarn but I have error like this and I can not find why I am doing this error

Answer (score 1):

You should use `yarn cache clean` or update yarn to the latest version